# CakePHP: Caching does not work

Tags: cakephp, caching

I am having the following issues: my cakephp app is not handling the cache thing properly. As suggested by every result in google, I created a function in the model to manually delete the cache:

```
public function afterSave($created) {
    Cache::clear();
    clearCache();
}
```

Unfortunately, this is doing nothing. Doesn't delete anything, and I still have the problem.

In case I have no explained myself properly, I will give an example of what happens:

I go with my browser to a page that shows a list of the last 5 records in my database. Then I go and add another record. I come back to the page that shows the last 5, and the information is not updated. It uses the cache and comes back with outdated info. If I press F5, then he page trully reloads and I see the trully 5 last records.

And that's it, I don't know what to do. The whole app works like crap, because you do something and it never appears unless you refresh the page with F5, which is something of course users are unaware, leading them to think "nothing was added" when it actually was.

Comment: Did you checked the modification date of the correspondent cache file after saving, to see if it is updated?? and after pressing F5??

Comment: I never touched a thing of cache. It was cake default handling.

I did this to solve the problem:

In the controllers, inside beforefilter function I made a check, if 'action' == 'whatever' --> disableCache

It did the job. The actions I choose now dont have cache, and everything works fine.

Comment: mmmm... that behavior sounds rare. You should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I can't respond my question cause I am basically a noob (says the site).

Comment: I did this to solve the problem: In the controllers, inside beforefilter function I made a check, if 'action' == 'whatever' --> disableCache It did the job.

The actions you choose won't have browser cache.

function beforeFilter(){

    if ($this->action == 'youraction'){
       $this->disableCache();
    }
    //your action is the action for which you don't want/need browser cache
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cache::clear()` will only clear entries that have expired.

Try `Cache::clear(FALSE)`. Works if you have CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve the problem: In the controllers, inside beforefilter function I made a check, if the action is something I disable the cache.

The actions you choose won't have browser cache.

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if ($this->action == 'youraction'){
       $this->disableCache();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of caching required lots of thinking, where to use where to not. If your update is frequent, don't use caching there.

We use caching where data rarely change, at that moment it is win-win situation.

***Cache::clear($check, $config = 'default')***

Destroy all cached values for a cache configuration.

[cakephp Caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html)